# Post Angular App as facebook Instant Article

Tags: angular, rss, facebook-instant-articles

I want to post my website made in Angular 4 as Instant Article . 
example:- when user open app.example.com on facebook contents of index.html will be loaded on Instant Article.

Comment: this question is really huge in scope, I suggest you break it down and ask specific question.

Comment: i am a bit new to this.
I was wondering can i load my angular [app](http://jain.outgrow.co.in/jain-12) inside instant article. Is it even possible without iframes

Comment: ok so your question is how to load an angular app inside a div tag of html?

Comment: No, i want instant article fully behaved like my app. means in article my javascript and index.html  will run

Comment: Can you elaborate about your page/article? The link you had mentioned is not working, can you provide an alternative link ?

Comment: This is an public link from my angular website the content in it is fully dynamic ,I want whenever http://jain.outgrow.co.in/jain-12 this link is posted in Facebook it will open as an instant article . It’s index.html is run in instant article

Comment: Simple answer: This is not possible. FB does not digest JavaScript or even CSS.

Answer (score 4):

The Facebook widget won't load your Custom / Random / JS-based HTML. Try:

- server-side HTML rendering and using the correct HTML tags you'll be able to do it.
- More HTML and less Angular for managing just the necessary aspects of your Web.

[Instant Article Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference)

[How-To Format](https://medium.com/future-of-mobile-web/how-to-format-a-facebook-instant-article-7950b5c0f2c1)